Can wave equation solutions be decomposed into "translational waves"?
Let $\psi$ be a (global, real-valued) solution to the unit-speed wave equation $(\partial_t^2 - \nabla_x^2)\psi = 0$, on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ with coordinates $ t ,x_1,\ldots,x_n$.
Let us view $S^{n-1}$ as the set of unit vectors (for the usual Euclidean norm) in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
My question is whether there exists a function $f : S^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\psi(t,x) = \int_{v \in S^{n-1}} f(v,x-vt) \,d\mu(v)
$$
for all $(t,x) \in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$? Here $\mu$ is the usual solid angle measure on $S^{n-1}$.
My guess is the answer is yes, but would anyone know how this is proved, or a reference that discusses this? (I apologize if this question is standard or basic; I don't have a lot of background in PDEs.) And if the answer is yes, then if moreover $\psi$ is of differentiability class $C^k$ (where $k\geq2$), is the same true for $f$?

Do you have any kinds of spatial domains or initial/boundary conditions in mind?

@Aruralreader Not specifically, but I am also happy with answers that cover specific cases such as those ones
